# Why it's showing in the final of the page the parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, parameters, hashmap

I'm doing a hash of Agenda concerts and in the index.html.erb is showing in the final of the page the parameters of @agendas. 
Parameters showed in the final:

```
[#<Agenda id: 12, title: "test to show the past shows", info: "testando se aparece shows passados!", date_concert: "2015-05-13", begin_time: "2000-01-01 21:11:00", end_time: "2000-01-01 00:11:00", created_at: "2015-07-20 23:13:05", updated_at: "2015-07-20 23:13:05", user_id: nil>, #<Agenda id: 8, title: "Festival MPB Goiânia, Brasil", info: "Festival de Música Popular Brasileira em Goiânia, ...", date_concert: "2015-07-20", begin_time: "2000-01-01 00:43:00", end_time: "2000-01-01 22:40:00", created_at: "2015-07-20 22:43:17", updated_at: "2015-07-20 22:43:17", user_id: nil>, #<Agenda id: 9, title: "Mota Live Project at Disco Bataplan.", info: "Mota Live Project at Disco Bataplan. \r\nIn the Fest...", date_concert: "2015-07-20", begin_time: "2000-01-01 00:03:00", end_time: "2000-01-01 01:10:00", created_at: "2015-07-20 22:46:23", updated_at: "2015-07-20 22:46:23", user_id: nil>, #<Agenda id: 1, title: "Heineken Jazz Festival - Donostia", info: "Heineken Jazz Festival in Donostia-San Sebastian w...", date_concert: "2015-07-23", begin_time: "2000-01-01 20:30:00", end_time: "2000-01-01 00:00:00", created_at: "2015-07-19 22:06:01", updated_at: "2015-07-20 16:54:19", user_id: 3>, #<Agenda id: 13, title: "OAHspkdbasbd", info: "sdfñsdñf", date_concert: "2015-07-24", begin_time: "2000-01-01 12:27:00", end_time: "2000-01-01 14:55:00", created_at: "2015-07-21 00:28:05", updated_at: "2015-07-21 00:28:05", user_id: nil>, #<Agenda id: 10, title: "Show teste", info: "Show teste, sample!", date_concert: "2015-07-27", begin_time: "2000-01-01 23:00:00", end_time: "2000-01-01 01:00:00", created_at: "2015-07-20 22:54:23", updated_at: "2015-07-20 22:58:31", user_id: nil>, #<Agenda id: 5, title: "Show Brasil Skol Event", info: "Concert with a Event SKol Beer", date_concert: "2015-08-02", begin_time: "2000-01-01 10:40:00", end_time: "2000-01-01 13:00:00", created_at: "2015-07-20 16:56:30", updated_at: "2015-07-20 16:56:30", user_id: nil>, #<Agenda id: 2, title: "Mota Project Live - Disco Gu", info: "Concierto del grupo Mota Project Live en la Disco ...", date_concert: "2015-08-03", begin_time: "2000-01-01 21:00:00", end_time: "2000-01-01 00:00:00", created_at: "2015-07-19 23:49:56", updated_at: "2015-07-20 16:53:07", user_id: 3>, #<Agenda id: 6, title: "BBK - Bilbao Live", info: "Concierto en el BBK Live!", date_concert: "2015-08-07", begin_time: "2000-01-01 19:00:00", end_time: "2000-01-01 20:00:00", created_at: "2015-07-20 17:01:14", updated_at: "2015-07-20 17:01:14", user_id: nil>, #<Agenda id: 7, title: "Show Donosti Indie Festival", info: "Festival Indie en la ciudad de Donosti-San Sebasti...", date_concert: "2015-08-09", begin_time: "2000-01-01 22:30:00", end_time: "2000-01-01 23:40:00", created_at: "2015-07-20 22:36:11", updated_at: "2015-07-20 22:36:11", user_id: nil>]
```

[image]

I don't want to show that parameters. Why occurs this?

my file index.html.erb is:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<div class="distance">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">


  <div class="agenda_concerts">
      <h1> Agenda Concerts </h1>
      <hr class="featurette-divider">

          <%= @agendas.each do |agenda| %>

            <% if agenda.date_concert.past? %>

            <% else %>
              <span class="title"><%= link_to agenda.title, agenda %></span>
              </br>
              <span class="info"><%= agenda.info %></span>
              </br>
              <span class="date">Date: <%= agenda.date_concert.to_formatted_s(:rfc822)  %></span>
              </br>
              <span class="begin_time">Begin: <%= agenda.begin_time.to_s(:time) %></span>
              </br>
              <span class="end_time">End: <%= agenda.end_time.to_s(:time) %></span>
              </br>
              <% if user_signed_in? %>
                <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_agenda_path(agenda) %></td>
                <%= link_to 'Destroy', agenda, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
              <% end %>
              <hr class="featurette-divider">
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

in my agendas_controller.erb is:

```
def index
    @agendas = Agenda.all
end
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<%= ...... %>
```

the code which you written between this display in UI where as

```
<%  ...... %>
```

the code which you written between this doesn't display in UI

Try this it will work

```
 <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
 <div class="distance">
 <div class="container">
 <div class="row">


 <div class="agenda_concerts">
  <h1> Agenda Concerts </h1>
  <hr class="featurette-divider">

      <% @agendas.each do |agenda| %>

        <% if agenda.date_concert.past? %>

        <% else %>
          <span class="title"><%= link_to agenda.title, agenda %></span>
          </br>
          <span class="info"><%= agenda.info %></span>
          </br>
          <span class="date">Date: <%= agenda.date_concert.to_formatted_s(:rfc822)  %></span>
          </br>
          <span class="begin_time">Begin: <%= agenda.begin_time.to_s(:time) %></span>
          </br>
          <span class="end_time">End: <%= agenda.end_time.to_s(:time) %></span>
          </br>
          <% if user_signed_in? %>
            <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_agenda_path(agenda) %></td>
            <%= link_to 'Destroy', agenda, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
          <% end %>
          <hr class="featurette-divider">
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 2):

You want `<% @agendas.each do |agenda| %>` instead of `<%= @agendas.each do |agenda| %>`

`<%= ... %>` and `<% ... %>` can both contain ruby statements. The first option will display what the ruby statement returns, and latter option tells your view not to display what the ruby code returns. Calling `@agendas.each` returns the agenda array, but you don't want to display it, so use the dash option `<% ... %>`